# Caching application files in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, file-io

I have two related question about the way django handles application files.

1. When a django application is launched (with dev server or loaded with apache/wsgi) are all the `*.py` application files loaded in memory/cache or they are `open`-ed  each time? Most probably this is related with pure python modules loading
2. For many request/response cycles in my application I have to open some configuration `json` files. These files are never sent to the user are only meant for business logic, but they are accessed many times. Would the `open` operation on files impact the performance and how could I load these files once at launch time and store them in a sort of cache for quick access?